# Swfit URLRequest POST How to make a request with duplicated parameter keys

Tags: swift, post, parameters, urlrequest

I'm currently working on a project which uses Inoreader APIs, and there is [one](https://www.inoreader.com/developers/edit-tag) required post request with duplicated parameter keys.

```
https://www.inoreader.com/reader/api/0/edit-tag?a=user/-/state/com.google/read&i=12345678&i=12345679
```

As you can see duplicated **`i`** parameters. I've tried below to set `httpBody` of `URLRequest`, failed silently.

```
var parameters = [String: Any]()
parameters["i"] = idArray
parameters["a"] = "user/-/state/com.google/read"
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])
request.httpBody = jsonData
// I omitted other codes for simplicity
```

Then I've tried to chain every element of `idArray` with "`&i=`", assigned it to `parameters["i"]`, also failed silently.

```
// chainedID was something like 123&i=456&i=789, to make it looks like as url example given by documentation
parameters["i"] = chainedID
```

How can I do that? This API is working perfectly with one item, but I can't get it work on multiple items. It claims will work with multiple items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the example that you posted and the ones that the [documentation](https://www.inoreader.com/developers/edit-tag) mentions, although the request is **POST** can accept parameters in the URL's **query**.

So, the solution would be to compose your request using `URLComponents`:

```
var components = URLComponents(string: "https://www.inoreader.com/reader/api/0/edit-tag")
var queryItems = [
    URLQueryItem(name: "a", value: "user/-/state/com.google/read")
]
idArray.forEach {
    queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name: "i", value: $0))
}
components?.queryItems = queryItems
guard let url = components?.url else { return }
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
```

and **not** use JSON parameters in the request's body.